# JavaScript: Combine highest key values of multiple arrays into a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

Let's say I have four arrays:

```
var arr1 = [117, 121, 18, 24];
var arr2 = [132, 19, 432, 23];
var arr3 = [32, 23, 137, 145];
var arr4 = [900, 332, 23, 19];
```

I need to create a new array from these, `arr5`, where key 1 is the highest number from key 1 of `arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3`, `arr4`, and the same for key 2, 3, etc. So I would have `arr5` as:

```
[900, 332, 432, 145]
```

What would be the simplest way of accomplishing this?

Please **no** jQuery, just plain vanilla JS.

Comment: Did you try something yourself yet?

Comment: Combine your 4 arrays with array concat and sort them descending with array sort and take the first 4 for your new array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution using simple for-loop and `Math.max()`. Assuming that your arrays have the same length:

```
var arr5 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arr5.push(Math.max(arr1[i], arr2[i], arr3[i], arr4[i]));
}
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of accomplishing this.
One would be using `Math.max` (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

While using the `spread operator` (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) you can do it like this:

```
arr5.push( Math.max(...arr1) );
arr5.push( Math.max(...arr2) );
// etc..
```

Maybe try yourself how to accomplish this with a dynamic input of arrays, maybe a little wrapping function for the `Math.max` call, where you pass all arrays you like and which returns an array with only the max values.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a proposal with two nested [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
var arr1 = [117, 121, 18, 24],
    arr2 = [132, 19, 432, 23],
    arr3 = [32, 23, 137, 145],
    arr4 = [900, 332, 23, 19],
    result = function (array) {
        var r = [];
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            a.forEach(function (b, i) {
                if (!( r[i] > b)) {
                    r[i] = b;
                }
            });
        });
        return r;
    }([arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4]);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this solution

```
var arr1 = [117, 121, 18, 24];
var arr2 = [132, 19, 432, 23];
var arr3 = [32, 23, 137, 145];
var arr4 = [900, 332, 23, 19];
var arr5 = [];

Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};


for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
   var arr=[arr1[i], arr2[i], arr3[i], arr4[i]];
   var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
   arr5.push(max);

}

console.log(arr5);
```

Answer (score 0):

***I think that you should use madox2's solution!***

That said – one way to tackle about your problem is to let your arrays form a matrix, transpose that matrix, and map Math.max over the resulting rows.

**Something like this:**

```
function transpose(m) {
    return m[0].map(function(_, i) {
        return m.map(function(arr) {
            return arr[i];
         });
    });
}
var arr5 = transpose([arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4]).map(function(e) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, e);
});
```